# Join and overlap sounds in Python

Tags: python, audio, wav

Is there any tool/library for Python that will allow me to manipulate sound files (`wav`/`mp3`)?

Desired operations are:

- Create a new audio file
- Place sounds on a timeline with specified volume level, allowing them to overlap

The ideal tool would be used like:

```
result = AudioFile(12)   # New 12 sec audio file

sounds = [load_sound(fname) for fname in soundfiles]

result.add(sounds[0], start_time=0)
result.add(sounds[1], start_time=2, volume_level=0.6)

result.save('result.wav')
```

The `result.wav` should now be a 12 seconds audio composed of sounds `0` and `1` that will overlap if sound `0` is longer than 2 seconds.

**Q:** Is there something like this out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can almost do this with just the standard library.

[`wave`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/wave.html) can parse and create WAV files. It can't do MP3 (or AAC or other file formats you probably care about); if that's a critical feature you'll need to turn to a third-party library, but there are tons of options. ([`pymad`](https://github.com/jaqx0r/pymad) was the first one that came up in a search, but you should do your own searches on PyPI and/or Google, because SO is not well-suited to get recommendations and opinions.)

[`audioop`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/audioop.html) lets you do simple operations on audio buffers—nothing too fancy, but enough to normalize, scale, and merge. And you can build what you want easily out of that.

If you want to do things at a higher level, there are bindings for well-known tools like `sox`, `libavcodec`/`ffmpeg`, etc. In my experience, every time I've needed to write something beyond a quick hack, I couldn't find anything with complete-enough, stable-enough bindings that met the relevant licensing requirements, but again, you'll have to search for yourself. Or, alternatively, just call the command-line tools with `subprocess`, which is usually a whole lot simpler.